# What does this command do: rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby on Rails. What does `RAILS_ENV=test` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails defines 3 default environments: development, test, and production. By default, most rails and rake commands run in the development environment. However, you can specify one of the others by setting the RAILS_ENV environment variable.

That command will run your migrations in your test database, instead of your development database.

Answer (score 1):

`RAILS_ENV` represents the environment that the rake task should run under as configured in the Rails application.  Passing the argument `RAILS_ENV=test` sets the Rails environment to run under the `test` configuration.

The environment configuration takes place in at least 2 key places - `config/database.yml` and `config/environments/some_environment.rb`.  Look around in those files to see how these configurations differ.

Answer (score 0):

It sets the environment variable `RAILS_ENV` to `"test"` in the rake command. Basically in the rake task:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV']
# => "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

It runs all the db migration scripts on the test db. Keep in mind you have to have the test db created already though